# Calling Sitefinity ListItems method from webservice throws exception

Tags: c#, telerik, sitefinity

I have the following piece of code on a Website that uses Sitefinity

I need to encapsulate that functionality an expose it as a method of a webservice

```
model.listaDirecciones = new List<SimpleTO>();

var calles = App.WorkWith().ListItems().Where(o => o.Parent.UrlName == "listado-direcciones-formularios-venta"
                                && o.Status == ContentLifecycleStatus.Live).Get().OrderBy(o => o.Ordinal);
foreach (var calle in calles)
{
    var item = new SimpleTO();
    item.id = calle.Title.ToUpper();
    item.nombre = Utilities.Html.StringMethodExtensions.HTMLtoTEXT(calle.Content).ToUpper();
    model.listaDirecciones.Add(item);
}
```

So I have created a WCF Webservice project and have added references to the following assemblies

- Telerik.Sitefinity.dll
- Telerik.Sitefinity.ContentModules.dll
- Telerik.Sitefinity.Model.dll

When calling the `App.WorkWith` line I am getting the following exception

```
{"The configuration 'ListsConfig' is not registered"}
```

With this stacktrace:

```
"   en Telerik.Sitefinity.Configuration.Config.VerifySectionRegistered(Type sectionType, String sectionName)\r\n   en Telerik.Sitefinity.Configuration.Config.GetSectionInternal(Type sectionType, Boolean safeMode, String sectionName)\r\n   en Telerik.Sitefinity.Configuration.Config.GetSectionPrivate(Type sectionType, Boolean safeMode, String sectionName)\r\n   en Telerik.Sitefinity.Configuration.Config.GetSectionPrivate[TSection](Boolean safeMode)\r\n   en Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Lists.ListsManager.get_ProvidersSettings()\r\n   en Telerik.Sitefinity.Data.ManagerBase`1.GetProvidersSettings()\r\n   en Telerik.Sitefinity.Data.ManagerBase`1.Initialize()\r\n   en Telerik.Sitefinity.Data.ManagerBase`1..ctor(String providerName, String transactionName)\r\n   en Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Lists.ListsManager..ctor()"
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: I suppose this code works if it is placed inside the Sitefinity project, doesn't it? Probably that's your best bet - create the service inside the SitefinityWebApp project

Comment: @VeselinVasilev that is not possible since this is a separate WCF project that needs to replicate that functionality

Comment: Could this be related? https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/The-configuration-DynamicModulesConfig-is-not-registered

Comment: @FredKleuver well that post is related to a web site and the error is not quite the same, but thanks for sharing that link